# не подгружается яваскрипт при аякс?

Tags: jquery, ajax

На обычной странице есть скрипт, задающий проверку полей в модальном окне ввода логина и пароля,
я нажимаю сабмит в этом попапе, и аяксом подгружается, что не верный логин и пароль, однако после подгрузки аякса следующий скрипт просто не работает.

Почему?
Например, скрипт

```js
$(".required").each(function(){}).on("blur", function() {
        if ($(this).val()!="") {
            if ($(this).hasClass("error")) {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        }else{
            if ($(this).hasClass("error")==false) {
                $(this).addClass("error");
            }
        }
    });
```

вроде стоит `on`.

Comment: К счастью, экстрасенсов не существует. Сообщество SOru - не исключение. Предоставьте код, ну хоть какой-нибудь, ну пожалуйста :)

Comment: @Alexxosipov, аякс представить не могу, потому что в jffiddle не вставишь,
или я что-то не понимаю.  Может, удасться по функции понять ?
Помогите, пож-ста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Использование `on` не означает автоматического делегирования обработки событий. Обработчик нужно прокреплять к родительскому элементу с указанием селектора для элементов, которые нас интересуют.

```
$(document).on("blur", ".required", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("error", $(this).val() == "");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделай так: (инструкция к google chrome, хотя другие браузеры тоже умеют)

1) Жми Ctrl+shift+i

2) Перейди во вкладку Network

3) Нажми свой сабмит и увидишь там файл который является обработчиком на сервере.

4) Кликни по нему и смотри вкладку Headers

5) В самом низу найди Form Data вот здесь и увидишь что случилось и где ошибка спряталась

Без кода это всё, что могу посоветовать

Comment: Кликни по нему и смотри вкладку Headers

5) В самом низу найди Form Data вот здесь и увидишь что случилось и где ошибка спряталась

я не нашла во вкладке Headers во вкладке network/

Может, вы знаете хорошую статью, а то я читала на learn.javascript.ru так и ничего не поняла... Буду признательна, если поможете, спасибо!